# createUser and login flow with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promise, angularfire

[In this git issue](https://github.com/exocom/angularFire/commit/43b16d844e3df7cad8614b792f31c6acfb20dae8) AngularFire disabled the auto-login functionality associated with `$createUser`.  ([The docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#createuser-email-password-nologin) are outdated.)

So what's the best practice / cleanest way to create a user and then log them in?

```
 app.factory('Auth', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope) { 
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

    var Auth = {
        register: function (user) {
            return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password);
        },
        login: function (user) {
            return auth.$login('password', user);
        },
        ...
```

Note: `$createUser` returns a md5 hash but [`$login`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#login-provider-options) uses plaintext password.

I'm new to promises. Thanks!

Comment: I thought the doc mention $createUser(email, password, [noLogin]), "Set the optional noLogin parameter to true to tell AngularFire not to automatically log into the new user account after it has been created". You passed null means after Auth.register() the user will be logon.

Comment: @wayne, check the git issue I linked to.  As of Feb 12th, this is no longer the case. Docs are outdated.

Comment: The hash you mentioned is for a gravatar id, not a hash of the password. Just use the same user/pass you utilized in createUser again for $login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize what Kato meant.  But now that I understand promises the solution is pretty straight forward:

```
    register: function (user) {
        return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password)
            .then(function() {
                return auth.$login('password', user);
            });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it. You have to use [q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or inject angular.$q.

```
app.factory('Auth', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope) { 
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
var deferred = Q.defer(); // from Q lib
// var deferred = $q.defer(); //angularjs q

var Auth = {
    register: function (user) {

        auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password)
        .then(function(result) {
          deferred.notify('user created.'); // optional notify progress
          return auth.$login('password', user); // return a new promise for chaining.
        },
        function(reason) {
          // createUser failed
          deferred.reject(reason);
        })
        .then(function(result) {
          // resolve the login promise return from above
          deferred.resolve(result);
        },
        function(reason) {
          // login failed
          deferred.reject(reason);
        });

        return deferred;
    },
    login: function (user) {
        return auth.$login('password', user);
    },
    ...
```