# firebaseSimpleLogin: $createUser Promise Not Resolving until Another Event Occurs

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm setting up registration/login functionality using angular, Firebase, and firebaseSimpleLogin. After reading over a few tutorials and [another Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316641/createuser-and-login-flow-with-promises), I've got the registration working with one small but important caveat: the promise on the SimpleLogin $createUser function isn't resolving until I click on a link or button on my html page. Here's my code:

**Register.html**

```
<div class="form-group" >
  <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" ng-model="cred.email"/>
  <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="cred.password"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="register()"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Main.Js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('AuthCtrl', 
  ['$scope',
   '$location',
   '$firebase', 
   '$firebaseSimpleLogin', 
   'loginService',

function AuthCtrl($scope, $location, $firebase, $firebaseSimpleLogin, 
  loginService) {

  $scope.register = function(){
    var user = {
      email: $scope.cred.email,
      password: $scope.cred.password
    };

    loginService.register(user);
 };
});
```

**loginService.js** (note FBURL is defined elsewhere)

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .factory('loginService', function($firebaseSimpleLogin, $rootScope, $location, 
   $timeout) {
     var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
     var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

     return {
      register: function (user) {
        return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password)
                .then(function(registeredUser) {
                   console.log(registeredUser);
                }
    )}
});
```

In the above loginService.js, I'm not seeing the console.log until I click a button or  element; however, the user is created in the Firebase Simple Login DB when I look online. As soon as I click a button or  element, the console.log shows. My guess as to the issue is that the promise from auth.$createUser() isn't getting resolved, but I cannot find out why that would be.

Comment: Versions used so we can try to verify?

Comment: "angular": "~1.0.7", angularfire: 0.7.1, firebase: 1.0.11. please let me know if you need any other versions and thank you for the help!

Comment: Kato - Based on your response and another issue I was having, I upgraded Angular and its components to ~1.2.16 and now the registration is working as expected (i.e., I no longer have to click a button to resolve the promise). I tested downgrading back to 1.0.7 and ran into the issue again (just to make sure something else hadn't changed). Many thanks for the response -- it put me on the right path to solving this issue!!

Comment: Great to know! I'll have a look at the versions and--at a minimum--make sure the requirements in docs are updated. Cheers.

Comment: Hey. I am running into the same issue, that the $createUser promise is not resolving:  AngularFire 0.8.2 - FireBase 1.0.21 - Simple Login 1.6.4 - Angular 1.2.21

Comment: have you tried an updated version of angular? if that doesn't work, try posting your code and i can take a look